# Can MSVC automatically optimize this case?

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-studio-2012, compiler-construction

If I have many classes that use other classes with purely virtual interfaces can the compiler optimize this to not have a virtual call in `Release Mode` with full optimizations enabled?

For instance I have a class `HardwareBuffer` that contains a pointer to `IHardwareResourceManager` that has a virtual method:

```
virtual void ReleaseBuffer(HardwareBuffer* buffer) = 0;
```

and in the Release method of `HardwareBuffer`, I call

```
m_pHardwareResourceManager->Release(this);
```

There is a single class `Render` that inherits `IHardwareResourceManager`, where I actually implement the virtual `Release` method. When I create a `HardwareBuffer`, I set its `m_pHardwareResourceManager` to the `Renderer` itself.

Can the call to `IHardwareResourceManager::Release` in the Release method of `HardwareBuffer` be devirtualized?

Comment: Your formatting hurts my eyes. Can you make this more readable?

Comment: this might be a little more readable as code. If I understand you correctly, I would say that in most cases virtual functions do not be optimized away. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141726/can-you-cache-a-virtual-function-lookup-in-c for more information.

Comment: There are a few cases where the type of a variable, even if its used in a polymorphic way, its unknown at compile-time, so when you are worried about virtual functions performance (VTABLE and its inherent instructions-cache fights), static-polymorphism through CRTP could be a good alternative

Comment: So, code something like this: http://pastebin.com/MwiSceUD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know when MSVC could accomplish it, but I do know that, in general, one would have to trace m_pHadwareResourceManager all the way back to the construction of `Render`.  It has to be careful: a DLL could always create a new instance of `IHardwareRResourceManager` and provide it to your application.  This is quite a daunting task, unless you allocated the `Render` object on the stack.

That being said, indirect lookups from a VTABLE like this are AGGRESSIVELY optimized at the hardware level, because they occur so often.  Make sure you profile before assuming the virtual function call is a large cost.  For example, I would not be surprised if, on x64, the indirect lookup is cheaper than the prologue and epilogue of the function you are calling.

For a comparison:  DirectX uses COM, which has a comparable indirect lookup on every function call.