# Implementig a C++ State Machine. How to solve Wpmf-convesion Warning?

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers, compiler-warnings, state-machine

I am trying to implement in C ++, the state machine described in this link for C language: https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/Coding-State-Machines.

I have created an Fsm class, which implements the behavior of the state machine, and a Machine class, whose methods will be the states.

The code works, but it generates a warning (-Wpmf-conversions) when I try to save the memory address of a Machine method, in State state__

```
class Fsm
{
public:
    typedef void (*State)();
private:
    State state__;
public:
    Fsm(State state);
    void dispatch();
}; 

Fsm::Fsm(State state)
{
    state__ = state ;
} //Fsm

void Fsm::dispatch()
{
    (*state__)() ;
}



class Machine : public Fsm
{
public:
    Machine() : Fsm((State)&Machine::initial) {}       // ctor
};
```

I expect to solve the -Wpmf-conversions warning.

Comment: `State` is a plain function pointer, not a pointer to member function. These two are very different. You may wish to consult your favorite C++ textbook for details.

Comment: `Fsm((State)&Machine::initial` -- You shouldn't cover up the compiler error like this.  The compiler would have told you what the issue was if you didn't do a C-style cast to `State`.  Remove the cast, read the error, and read the previous comment by @IgorTandetnik

Comment: I'm not covering up compiler errors. When using embedded systems, New and Delete operator is not available. So, like malloc and free must be used for working with objects, it is not a good idea to use a conventional state pattern, instantiating new objects for each state. 
So I'm using this State machine solution proposed by Barr Group: https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/Coding-State-Machines.
That example uses that casting too, but I think they just dismissed that warning

Comment: If you look at it logically, how would this callback work?  To call a non-static member function, you need to specify the object in the call.  You can't simply say `(*func)()` or similar to make the call.  The syntax is `(object->*func)()` or `(object.*func)()`.  So where would `object` be coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`State` does correspond to a function pointer.

Unfortunately, you have not provided a definition for `initial` in your code. So it's a little guess. But in your constructor's argument `(State)&Machine::initial` you seem to assume it's a static member function.

This compiles without errors or warnings:

```
class Machine : public Fsm
{
    static void initial();    // make sure it's static 
public:
    Machine() : Fsm((State)&Machine::initial) {}       // ctor
};
```

Now if you want a pointer to a member function, it's another story.  First, you'd need to define `State` accordingly:

```
typedef void (Fsm::*State)();
```

Then the `dispatch` must invoke a member function:

```
void Fsm::dispatch()
{
    (this->*state__)() ;
}
```

The only issue could be that you call a derived member function pointer by using a base member function pointer.  Fortunately, this is guaranteed to work, as explained in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37662548/3723423).

Comment: Thanks!! Totally works.
The second answer is the one I needed. I'm using a pointer to a member function.