# Would using a virtual destructor make non-virtual functions do v-table lookups?

Tags: c++, oop, crtp, vtable

Just what the topic asks. Also want to know why non of the usual examples of CRTP do not mention a `virtual` dtor.

EDIT: 
Guys, Please post about the CRTP prob as well, thanks.

Comment: Why would you think that non-virtual functions might do a v-table lookup when a virtual destructor exists?

Comment: hmmm. Good point! Just that I do not think that. I am not sure what happens, that is why I'm asking :D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only virtual functions require dynamic dispatch (and hence *vtable* lookups) and not even in all cases. If the compiler is able to determine at compile time what is the *final overrider* for a method call, it can elide performing the dispatch at runtime. User code can also disable the dynamic dispatch if it so desires:

```
struct base {
   virtual void foo() const { std::cout << "base" << std::endl; }
   void bar() const { std::cout << "bar" << std::endl; }
};
struct derived : base {
   virtual void foo() const { std::cout << "derived" << std::endl; }
};
void test( base const & b ) {
   b.foo();      // requires runtime dispatch, the type of the referred 
                 // object is unknown at compile time.
   b.base::foo();// runtime dispatch manually disabled: output will be "base"
   b.bar();      // non-virtual, no runtime dispatch
}
int main() {
   derived d;
   d.foo();      // the type of the object is known, the compiler can substitute
                 // the call with d.derived::foo()
   test( d );
}
```

On whether you should provide virtual destructors in all cases of inheritance, the answer is no, not necessarily. The virtual destructor is required only if code `delete`s objects of the derived type held through pointers to the base type. The common rule is that you should

- *provide a public virtual destructor or a protected non-virtual destructor*

The second part of the rule ensures that user code cannot delete your object through a pointer to the base, and this implies that the destructor need not be virtual. The advantage is that if your class does not contain any virtual method, this will not change any of the properties of your class --the memory layout of the class changes when the first virtual method is added-- and you will save the vtable pointer in each instance. From the two reasons, the first being the important one.

```
struct base1 {};
struct base2 {
   virtual ~base2() {} 
};
struct base3 {
protected:
   ~base3() {}
};
typedef base1 base;
struct derived : base { int x; };
struct other { int y; };
int main() {
   std::auto_ptr<derived> d( new derived() ); // ok: deleting at the right level
   std::auto_ptr<base> b( new derived() );    // error: deleting through a base 
                                              // pointer with non-virtual destructor
}
```

The problem in the last line of main can be resolved in two different ways. If the `typedef` is changed to `base1` then the destructor will correctly be dispatched to the `derived` object and the code will not cause undefined behavior. The cost is that `derived` now requires a virtual table and each instance requires a pointer. More importantly, `derived` is no longer layout compatible with `other`. The other solution is changing the `typedef` to `base3`, in which case the problem is solved by having the compiler yell at that line. The shortcoming is that you cannot delete through pointers to base, the advantage is that the compiler can statically ensure that there will be no undefined behavior.

In the particular case of the CRTP pattern (excuse the redundant *pattern*), most authors do not even care to make the destructor protected, as the intention is not to hold objects of the derived type by references to the base (templated) type. To be in the safe side, they should mark the destructor as protected, but that is rarely an issue.

Comment: This and Steve Jessop's answer are both informative. I am split between the two. Will mark this as solved just due to your rep being lower :D.

Answer (score 5):

Very unlikely indeed. There's nothing in the standard to *stop* compilers doing whole classes of stupidly inefficient things, but a non-virtual call is still a non-virtual call, regardless of whether the class has virtual functions too. It has to call the version of the function corresponding to the static type, not the dynamic type:

```
struct Foo {
    void foo() { std::cout << "Foo\n"; }
    virtual void virtfoo() { std::cout << "Foo\n"; }
};
struct Bar : public Foo {
    void foo() { std::cout << "Bar\n"; }
    void virtfoo() { std::cout << "Bar\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Bar b;
    Foo *pf = &b;  // static type of *pf is Foo, dynamic type is Bar
    pf->foo();     // MUST print "Foo"
    pf->virtfoo(); // MUST print "Bar"
}
```

So there's absolutely no need for the implementation to put non-virtual functions in the vtable, and indeed in the vtable for `Bar` you'd need two different slots in this example for `Foo::foo()` and `Bar::foo()`. That means it would be a special-case use of the vtable even if the implementation *wanted* to do it. In practice it doesn't want to do it, it wouldn't make sense to do it, don't worry about it.

CRTP base classes really ought to have destructors that are non-virtual and protected.

A virtual destructor is required if the user of the class might take a pointer to the object, cast it to the base class pointer type, then delete it. A virtual destructor means this will work. A protected destructor in the base class stops them trying it (the `delete` won't compile since there's no accessible destructor). So either one of virtual or protected solves the problem of the user accidentally provoking undefined behavior.

See guideline #4 here, and note that "recently" in this article means nearly 10 years ago:

http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm

No user will create a `Base<Derived>` object of their own, that isn't a `Derived` object, since that's not what the CRTP base class is for. They just don't need to be able to access the destructor - so you can leave it out of the public interface, or to save a line of code you can leave it public and rely on the user not doing something silly.

The reason it's undesirable for it to be virtual, given that it doesn't need to be, is just that there's no point giving a class virtual functions if it doesn't need them. Some day it might cost something, in terms of object size, code complexity or even (unlikely) speed, so it's a premature pessimization to make things virtual always. The preferred approach among the kind of C++ programmer who uses CRTP, is to be absolutely clear what classes are for, whether they are designed to be base classes at all, and if so whether they are designed to be used as polymorphic bases. CRTP base classes aren't.

The reason that the user has no business casting to the CRTP base class, even if it's public, is that it doesn't really provide a "better" interface. The CRTP base class depends on the derived class, so it's not as if you're switching to a more general interface if you cast `Derived*` to `Base<Derived>*`. No other class will ever have `Base<Derived>` as a base class, unless it also has `Derived` as a base class. It's just not useful as a polymorphic base, so don't make it one.

Comment: "to save a line of code you can leave it public and rely on the user not doing something silly" and that is a very bad idea, laziness in this case is frowned upon

Comment: @the_drow: sure, but some coding guidelines are reasonably relaxed about whether the `public` interface is exactly right. As long as the *published* interface is right, then it's great for everything else to be inaccessible, but it's not the kind of thing that all people are always going to bother with. Especially when showing you their clever CRTP class in some blog post ;-) So I suppose what I mean is, don't necessarily assume that what you see has a good reason and is best possible practice.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: And why do you think that this guidline should be relaxed and when? I still upvoted you btw :)

Comment: @the_drow: I don't think it *should* be relaxed. I think CRTP base classes "really ought" to have protected destructors. I'm just speaking in terms of what I expect nakiya will have seen. Also covering my ass, because I can say with very high confidence that if you find an example on SO of me writing a CRTP base class, it will have the default public destructor (i.e. I won't have written one) ;-)

Comment: The more general guideline "get the public interface right" can be relaxed if all your programmers have experience of using C or Python competently, and can be trusted not to always automatically call every function and access every data member they see in the source (e.g. header file), regardless of whether it's actually documented. It's still better to get it right, though.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your first question: No. Only calls to virtual functions will cause an indirection via the virtual table at runtime.

The answer to your second question: The [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) is commonly implemented using private inheritance. You don't model an 'IS-A' relationship and hence you don't pass around pointers to the base class.

For instance, in

```
template <class Derived> class Base
{
};

class Derived : Base<Derived>
{
};
```

You don't have code which takes a `Base<Derived>*` and then goes on to call delete on it. So you never attempt to delete an object of a derived class through a pointer to the base class. Hence, the destructor doesn't need to be virtual.

Comment: +1. The point I see in RTCP is unification of implementation in the Base class using templates. I do not see any case in which we have to use Base<Derived>*

Comment: Now I'm confused as to if there is any use of CRTP at all unless you have an unidentified base object doing something for the concrete object in the background. Is there any other use?

Comment: @nakiya: The CRTP is one tool to implement static polymorphism. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262254/c-crtp-to-avoid-dynamic-polymorphism/262984#262984 for a nice example.

Comment: Note that the example is flawed in that the inheritance in that case is not private, but rather public. `struct derived : base {}` is equivalent to `class derived : public base {}`. But the overall argument holds.

Comment: @ David Rodríguez - dribeas: Ah, you're right. I adjusted my example accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong. It's totally legal and reasonable(what reasons? see this link: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/12/05/the-cost-of-dynamic-virtual-calls-vs-static-crtp-dispatch-in-c) to model Is-A relationship with CRTP. Correct me if I'm wrong - cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think the answer to the OP's question has been answered quite well - that's a solid NO.

But, is it just me going insane or is something going seriously wrong in the community? I felt a bit scared to see so many people suggesting that it's useless/rare to hold a pointer/reference to Base. Some of the popular answers above suggest that we don't model IS-A relationship with CRTP, and I completely disagree with those opinions.

It's widely known that there's no such thing as interface in C++. So to write testable/mockable code, a lot of people use ABC as an "interface". For example, you have a function `void MyFunc(Base* ptr)` and you can use it this way: `MyFunc(ptr_derived)`. This is the conventional way to model IS-A relationship which requires vtable lookups when you call any virtual functions in MyFunc. So this is pattern one to model IS-A relationship.

In some domain where performance is critical, there exists another way(pattern two) to model IS-A relationship in a testable/mockable manner - via CRTP. And really, performance boost can be impressive(600% in the article) in some cases, see this [link](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/12/05/the-cost-of-dynamic-virtual-calls-vs-static-crtp-dispatch-in-c). So MyFunc will look like this `template<typename Derived> void MyFunc(Base<Derived> *ptr)`. When you use MyFunc, you do `MyFunc(ptr_derived);` The compiler is going to generate a copy of code for MyFunc() that matches best with the parameter type ptr_derived - `MyFunc(Base<Derived> *ptr)`. Inside MyFunc, we may well assume some function defined by the interface is called, and pointers are statically cast-ed at compile time(check out the impl() function in the link), there's no overheads for vtable lookups.

Now, can someone please tell me either I am talking insane nonsense or the answers above simply did not consider the second pattern to model IS-A relationship with CRTP?

Comment: I agree with you, I'd like to hear more from the people who answered above!