# Class with multiple return types?

Tags: c++

I'm making a game gui api. It will work with both Allegro and SDL. I use polymorphism for input and bitmap drawing. The issue comes with these 3 types: Bitmap, Font, and Color. SDL and Allegro are different on these. The problem is I cannot really use polymorphism here due to different return types. I wouldn't feel right to have a void* as the return type. What could I do instead so that the user could just do:

```
AGBitmap bmp = AGBitmap("someimage.png");
graphics->draw(bmp);
```

Right now my AGBitmap works with only Allegro and has an overloaded = operator and manages its memory so the user does not have to.

What could I do?

Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of questions on StackOverflow. If you want the people who can answer yours to find it, you'll have to do better on the title.

Comment: You'd think he knew better after 3 kilopoints

Comment: Functions return stuff, not classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are different types, you should use template specialization.

```
template < typename WinManagerType >
class AGBitmap;

template<>
class AGBitmap< AlegroWinType >
{
 public :
   //...
   AlegroBitmapType GetBitmap();
};

template<>
class AGBitmap< SdlWinType >
{
 public :
   //...
   SdlBitmapType GetBitmap();
};
```

But since your question is so vague, there might be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an application for a [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

[CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262254/c-crtp-to-avoid-dynamic-polymorphism) might be useful in this scenario, provided you can abstract a common interface for the relevant concrete classes into your base class template(s).

```
template <class BITMAP> class MyBitmap
{
  // generic bitmap interface
};

class MyAGBitmap : MyBitmap<AGBitmap>
{
};
```