# Example usage of propagate_on_container_move_assignment

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator

I'm trying to understand how to properly write [**AllocatorAware**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/AllocatorAwareContainer) containers.

My understandings is that the `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` typedef indicates whether or not a certain `Allocator` type needs to be copied when the Container itself is move-assigned.

So, since I can't find any examples of this, my own stab at it would be something like the following:

Given a container type `Container`, an `Allocator` type `allocator_type`, and an internal `allocator_type` data member `m_alloc`:

```
Container& operator = (Container&& other)
{
  if (std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value)
  {
     m_alloc = std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::select_on_container_copy_construction(
      other.m_alloc
     );
  }

  return *this;
}
```

Is this correct?

Also, another source of confusion here is that the nested typedefs `propagate_on_container_move/copy_assignment` are specifically talking about *assignment*... but what about constructors?  Does a move constructor or copy constructor of an `AllocatorAware` container *also* need to check these typedefs ?  I would think the answer would be *yes* here..., meaning, I'd also need to write:

```
Container(Container&& other)
{
      if (std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment::value)
      {
         m_alloc = std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::select_on_container_copy_construction(
          other.m_alloc
         );
      }
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I recommend studying the `<vector>` header of [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org).  You'll have to deal with all of the nasty underscores std::lib implementors are required to use.  But libc++ has a C++11-conforming implementation, there for the inspecting.

**move assignment operator**

The container move assignment operator must deal with three separate possibilities:

1. `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is true.
2. `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is false, and the allocators from the lhs and rhs compare equal.
3. `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is false, and the allocators from the lhs and rhs compare unequal.

When possible, the decision between these three cases should be made at compile time, not run time.  Specifically, one should choose between the sets {1} and {2, 3} at compile time, since `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is a compile time constant.  Compile-time branching on a compile-time constant is often done with [tag dispatching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23976925/576911), instead of with an if-statement as you show.

In none of these cases should `select_on_container_copy_construction` be used.  That function is *only* for the container copy constructor.

In case 1, the lhs should first use the lhs's allocator to deallocate all memory that has been allocated.  This must be done first because the rhs allocator may not be able to deallocate this memory later.  Then the lhs allocator is move-assigned from the rhs allocator (just like any other move assignment).  Then memory ownership is transferred from the rhs container to the lhs container.  If the design of your container is such that the rhs container can not be left in a resource-less state (a poor design imho), then a new resource can be allocated by the moved-from rhs allocator for the rhs container.

When `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` is false, you must choose between cases 2 and 3 at run time, since the allocator comparison is a run time operation.

In case 2, you can do the same thing as in case 1, *except* do not move assign the allocators.  Just skip that step.

In case 3, you can not transfer ownership of any memory from the rhs container to the lhs container.  The only thing you can do is as if:

```
assign(make_move_iterator(rhs.begin()), make_move_iterator(rhs.end()));
```

Note that in case 1, because the algorithm has been chosen at compile-time, the `value_type` of the container need not be `MoveAssignable` nor `MoveInsertable` (`MoveConstructible`) to move-assign the container.  But in case 2, the `value_type`s *do* have to be `MoveAssignable` and `MoveInsertable` (`MoveConstructible`), even though they never are, because you are choosing between 2 and 3 at run time.  And 3 needs these operations on the `value_type` to do the `assign`.

The move assignment operator is easily the most complicated special member to implement for containers.  The rest are much easier:

**move constructor**

The move constructor just move constructs the allocator and steals the resources from the rhs.

**copy constructor**

The copy constructor gets its allocator from `select_on_container_copy_construction(rhs.m_alloc)`, and then uses that to allocate resources for the copy.

**copy assignment operator**

The copy assignment operator must first check if `propagate_on_container_copy_assignment` is true.  If it is, and if the lhs and rhs allocators compare unequal, then the lhs must first deallocate all memory, because it won't be able to do so later after the allocators are copy assigned.  Next, if `propagate_on_container_copy_assignment`, copy assign the allocators, else do not.  Then copy the elements:

```
assign(rhs.begin(), rhs.end());
```

Comment: What about the case where `propagate_on_move_assignment` is true, but the allocators from lhs and rhs compare unequal?  If `propagate_on_move_assignment` is true, shouldn't we first check if the allocators compare equal, and if they are equal, we don't need to deallocate all memory before move-assigning the allocators.  (This way we can reuse already allocated memory)

Comment: If your container design is such that you can transfer ownership of all memory from rhs to lhs, then there is no need to reuse any memory on the lhs.  However if you can not transfer all memory, it can be handy to reuse the memory on the lhs if it can not be supplied by the rhs, and if the allocators are equal.  My bias is that a container design is best when 100% of the memory can be transferred, leaving the rhs in a resource-less state.

Comment: Since C++17, `if constexpr` can be used to seperate {1} and {2,3}.

Comment: I guessed that this was Howard Hinnant answering before I got to the bottom of the answer!