# C++ Overload an overrided method

Tags: c++

Is it possible in C++ to overload in the child classes an overrided method?
I'm asking this because I have many child classes that although they are the same (in my case game objects) they interact in different ways with each others.
So, I need to create a function like `void processCollision(GameObject obj)` in the superclass.
But that could be overloaded in the child classes depending on the class of the `GameObject` (if it's a building, a car ...).

I'm just trying to run from the alternative which is using upcasting and RTTI.

Comment: Do you know the difference between overriding and overloading?  Overrides have the same signature, overloads have different signatures.  If you make your overloads virtual, then you can override them.

Comment: You will probably get better feedback if instead of asking "Is X possible", you instead explain in detail what problem you're trying to solve and show what you've tried so far.

Comment: I added some more info. the problem is that I could overload the function processCollision, but if I do that I'll need to include the Gameobject child classes, and that will create a dependency cicle.

Comment: If possible, please post some code that illustrates what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to implement is normally called "[multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch)" and unfortunately C++ doesn't support it directly (because in C++ view methods are bounded with classes and there are no multimethods).

Any C++ solution will require some coding for the implementation.

One simple symmetric way to implement it is to create a map for the supported cases:

```
typedef void (*Handler)(Obj *a, Obj *b);
typedef std::map<std::pair<OType, OType>, Handler> HandlerMap;

HandlerMap collision_handlers;
```

then the collision handling is:

```
HandlerMap::iterator i =
    collision_handlers.find(std::make_pair(a->type, b->type));
if (i != collision_handlers.end()) i->second(a, b);
```

and the code goes in a free function.

If speed is a key factor and the object type can be coded in a small integer (e.g. 0...255) the dispatch could become for example:

```
collision_handlers[(a->type<<8)+b->type](a, b);
```

where collision handler is just an array of function pointers, and the speed should be equivalent to a single virtual dispatch.

The wikipedia link at the start of the answer lists another more sophisticated option for C++ (the visitor pattern).

Comment: Another more complex solution to the problem of multiple dispatch in C++ is the Visitor Pattern.

Comment: @YoungJohn: It's listed in the wikipedia article I linked, but I added an explicit reference to it anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Do you intend `OType` to be something like `typeid(ConcreteGameObject)`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I personally never found `typeid` very useful and I normally prefer either a regular data member or a virtual member returning an value if a data member size is a problem and the class has virtual methods anyway. Also for the second (fast) approach of double dispatch you need the class identification to be a small integer (directly usable as index) and `typeid` doesn't provide that.

Answer (score 2):

> *"I'm just trying to run from the alternative which is using upcasting and RTTI."*

Virtual polymorphism doesn't need upcasting or RTTI. Usually that's what virtual member functions are for:

```
 class GameObject {
 public:
     virtual void processCollision(GameObject& obj);
 };

 class SomeGameObject1 : public GameObject {
 public:
     // SomeGameObject1's version of processCollision()
     virtual void processCollision(GameObject& obj) {
         // e.g here we also call the base class implementation
         GameObject::processCollision();

         // ... and add some additional operations
     }
 };

 class SomeGameObject2 : public GameObject {
 public:
     // SomeGameObject2's version of processCollision()
     virtual void processCollision(GameObject& obj) {
         // Here we leave the base class implementation aside and do something 
         // completely different ...
     }
 };
```

**MORE ADDITIONS AND THOUGHTS**

As you're mentioning upcasting I'd suspect you want to handle collisions differently, depending on the actual `GameObject` type passed. This indeed would require upcasting (and thus RTTI) like follows

```
class Building : public GameObject {
public:
     virtual void processCollision(GameObject& obj) {
          Car* car = dynamic_cast<Car*>(&obj);
          Airplane* airplane = dynamic_cast<Airplane*>(&obj);

          if(car) {
              car->crash();
          }
          else if(airplane) {
              airplane->crash();
              collapse();
          }

          void collapse(); 
     };
```

Based on the above, that makes me contemplative about some design/architectural principles:

- May be it's not the best idea to place the `processCollision()` implementation strategy to the `GameObject` classes themselves. These shouldn't know about each other (otherwise it will be tedious to introduce new `GameObject` types to the model)
- You should introduce a kind of `GameManager` class that keeps track of moving/colliding `GameObject` instances, and chooses a `GameObjectCollisionStrategy` class implementing `void processCollision(GameObject& a,GameObject& b);` based on the actual types of `a` and `b`.
- For choosing the strategy, and resolve the final `GameObject` implementations and corresponding strategies, you should concentrate all of that *business knowdlege* to a `CollisionStrategyFactory`, and delegate to this.

---

The latter would look something like this

```
class GameObjectCollisionStrategy {
public:
    virtual processCollision(GameObject& a,GameObject& b) const = 0;
};

class CollideBuildingWithAirplane : public GameObjectCollisionStrategy {
public:
    virtual void processCollision(GameObject& a,GameObject& b) const {
         Building* building = dynamic_cast<Building*>(a);
         Airplane* airplane = dynamic_cast<Airplane*>(b);
         if(building && airplane) {
             airplane->crash();
             building->collapse();
         }
    }
};

class CollideBuildingWithCar : public GameObjectCollisionStrategy {
public:
    virtual void processCollision(GameObject& a,GameObject& b) const {
         Building* building = dynamic_cast<Building*>(a);
         Car* car = dynamic_cast<Car*>(b);
         if(building && car) {
             car->crash();
         }
    }
};
```

---

```
class CollisionStrategyFactory {
public:
    static const GameObjectCollisionStrategy& chooseStrategy
       (GameObject* a, GameObject* b) {
        if(dynamic_cast<Building*>(a)) {
            if(dynamic_cast<Airplane*>(b)) {
                return buildingAirplaneCollision;
            }
            else if(dynamic_cast<Car*>(b)) {
                return buildingCarCollision;
            }
        }
        return defaultCollisionStrategy;
    }

private:
    class DefaultCollisionStrategy : public GameObjectCollisionStrategy {
    public:
        virtual void processCollision(GameObject& a,GameObject& b) const {
           // Do nothing.
        }
    };

    // Known strategies
    static CollideBuildingWithAirplane buildingAirplaneCollision;
    static CollideBuildingWithCar buildingCarCollision;
    static DefaultCollisionStrategy defaultCollisionStrategy;
};
```

---

```
class GameManager {
public:
    void processFrame(std::vector<GameObject*> gameObjects) {
        for(std::vector<GameObject*>::iterator it1 = gameObjects.begin();
            it1 !=  gameObjects.end();
            ++it1) {
            for(std::vector<GameObject*>::iterator it2 = gameObjects.begin();
                it2 !=  gameObjects.end();
                ++it2) {
                if(*it1 == *it2) continue;
                if(*it1->collides(*it2)) {
                    const GameObjectCollisionStrategy& strategy = 
                        CollisionStrategyFactory::chooseStrategy(*it1,*it2); 
                    strategy->processCollision(*(*it1),*(*it2));
                }
            }         
        }
    }
};
```

---

---

Alternatively you may want to opt for *static polymorphism*, which also works without RTTI, but needs all types known at compile time. The basic pattern is the so called [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262254/crtp-to-avoid-dynamic-polymorphism).

That should look as follows

```
 class GameObject {
 public:
     // Put all the common attributes here
     const Point& position() const;
     const Area& area() const;
     void move(const Vector& value);
 };

 template<class Derived>
 class GameObjectBase : public GameObject {
 public:
      void processCollision(GameObject obj) {
          static_cast<Derived*>(this)->processCollisionImpl(obj);
      }
 };


 class SomeGameObject1 : public GameObjectBase<SomeGameObject1 > {
 public:
     // SomeGameObject1's version of processCollisionImpl()
     void processCollisionImpl(GameObject obj) {
     }
 };

 class SomeGameObject2 : public GameObjectBase<SomeGameObject2 > {
 public:
     // SomeGameObject2's version of processCollisionImpl()
     void processCollisionImpl(GameObject obj) {
     }
 };
```

But this would unnecessarily complicate the design, and I doubt it will provide any benefits for your use case.

Comment: But the processCollision is deferent depending on the Gameobject child class. (SomeGameObject1, SomeGameObject2 ...)´

Comment: @LuisAlves - `But the processCollision is deferent depending on the Gameobject child class`  Exactly.  That's the point of virtual functions.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not explicit, I would like to create the methods processCollision(SomeGameObject1 obj) and  processCollision(SomeGameObject2 obj). I would like to do something like what the visitor does (upcasting an object using overloaded methods) but I can't since if I define the methods processCollision(SomeGameObject1 obj) and  processCollision(SomeGameObject2 obj) in the GameObject, I'll have a circular dependency.

Comment: @LuisAlves - `virtual void processCollision(GameObject& obj); `  Now there is no circular dependency if you `forward declare` GameObject.  Note that a `reference` parameter is used.

Comment: @LuisAlves - is SomeGameObject actually derived from GameObject?  If so, then there already is a dependency.

Comment: All SomeGameObject extend GameObject. (also they are all in separated files)

Comment: @LuisAlves So you are including the header that defines `GameObject` within the header that defines `SomeGameObject`?  That's the only way that `class SomeGameObject : public GameObject {` is going to compile without error.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that to have the methods processCollision(SomeGameObject1 obj) and processCollision(SomeGameObject2 obj), I'll need to include SomeGameObject1 and SomeGameObject2 headers in the GameObject. which will give me a circular dependency

Comment: @LuisAlves _"Yes, the problem is that to have the methods processCollision(SomeGameObject1 obj) and processCollision(SomeGameObject2 obj)"_ Well, _overriding_ the base class method doesn't let you change the parameter type in the function signature. As you want something like ` processCollision(SomeGameObject1 obj)` you in fact need ` processCollision(GameObject& obj)` as signature in the base and derived class. But to determine if `GameObject&` actually is a `SomeGameObject1&` reference, you'll in fact need `dynamic_cast<>` and RTTI.

Comment: @LuisAlves You should take on R. Sahu's advice BTW, and illustrate your question with a concise code sample that reproduces those problems you claimed.