# inheriting from child and calling child's function not working in visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, inheritance

In the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T >
class Setting
{
public:
    Setting(Setting* instance){
        ((T*)instance)->write();
    };
    Setting(){ write(); };
    virtual void write(){ cout << "in parent\n"; }
};

class child :public Setting<child>
{
public:
    child() :Setting(this){};
    virtual void write(){ cout << "in child\n"; }
};
int main()
{
    child ch;
}
```

g++ prints `"in child"` which is exactly what I want .( http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4304ab99ebd894b3)

But in *visual studio 2013* output is `"in parent"`  !!!(http://rextester.com/EMQ5448)

why?? Is there any alternative way for getting the same result in visual studio?

Comment: Try a `static_cast<T*>(instance)` or even simpler (without need for `instance`): `static_cast<T*>(this)`

Comment: it is I believe nothing to do with visual studio but `visual c++`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962132/calling-virtual-functions-inside-constructors mvcc is not a standard complaint compiler. In general, calling virtual functions from the constructor has a pretty bad code smell...

Comment: `Setting(){ static_cast<T*>(this)->write(); };`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ not working http://rextester.com/OPX32838

Comment: Your code is wrong, it shouldn't work like you wish, looks like gcc 4.9 bug. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @omid Remove the `virtual` from the `write` signatures and [it works](http://rextester.com/XDU51563) as you expect it! Take some time an read about how CRTP is intended to work.

Comment: @ForEveR I want to call virtual functions in base class constructor for initializing some member variable . I want a better way of designing my class  instead of duplicating the same code for childs . http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96c1fd34299c9f9b

Comment: @omid You can't call virtual functions from a base class constructor, period.

Comment: @omid you can't. Instead write function in base, that should be called in derived c-tor. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44cea00d71c4b641

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"why?? Is there any alternative way for getting the same result in visual studio?"*

Because compiler implementations seem to differ when handling this syntax.
It seems like if `write()` is declared as a `virtual` function, VS2013 always tries to resolve it from the vtable, instead of using the method from the (not yet) instantiated derived class (disrespecting the `static_cast<>`).

I've got your sample working when removing the `virtual` keywords from your `write()` function declarations, like this

```
template<class T >
class Setting {
public:
    Setting(){ static_cast<T*>(this)->write(); };

    void write(){ cout << "in parent\n"; } // Note: No virtual
};

class child :public Setting<child> {
public:
    child() {};
    void write(){ cout << "in child\n"; }  // Note: No virtual
};

int main() {
    child ch;
}
```

---

Though this works, you seriously should obey, not to rely on any state established from the `child` class constructor, when calling `write` from the base class.

---

You also want to read about some additional references what the [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262254/crtp-to-avoid-dynamic-polymorphism) pattern, and using *static polymorphism* (that's all about avoiding the `virtual`) actually is about.