# Change Operation at runtime in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a small problem at hand. Suppose there is a if condition with only 2 operands but I want to make the operation dynamic.

```
void somFunc()
{
  if(a && b) /*1*/
  {
  }
  else if(a1 && b1) /*2*/
  {
  }
  else if(a || b) /*3*/
  {
  }
  else if(a1 || b1) /*4*/
}
```

Basically, 1 and 3 exactly has same parameters with different operation,Similarly for 2 and 4. I want to reduce these 4 operations to 2.
I want to know if there is a way I can make **oper** dynamic. Consider we only have 2 operations && and ||
Can I use templates in any way ?
If someone wants to know why I need this is, there are n if conditions inside a big if/else. If I somehow achieve this, I reduce the conditions by half.

Comment: You can not introduce specific keywords like `oper` here, but you could make a function `oper()` that takes two parameters and return a `boolean`.
If you want to go even further you can give that function as a parameter to `somFunc` to make it even more generic

Comment: @Damien. I understand your point. A bit of background to my problem is that this is a small and constrained rule engine where rules are defined externally including the operation. Sample condition will be if (X exists) and (Y not exists). or something like if (X exists) or (Y exists).

Comment: @Ajit Thanks for clarification. In this case the two answers already provided should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for, but you can write something like this:

```
enum OPERATION { AND, OR }; 

bool operation(bool a, bool b,OPERATION op) {
    if (op == AND) return a && b;
    return a || b;
}    

void somFunc(OPERATION op)
{
    if(operation(a,b,op)) 
    {
    }
}
```

Or as suggested in a comment, make the operation to be performed a parameter of the function, like so

```
template <OPERATION> 
void somFunc(OPERATION op)
{
    if(op(a,b)) 
    {
    }
}
```

and call it like this

```
somFunc( [](bool a, bool b) { return a && b; });
somFunc( [](bool a, bool b) { return a || b; });
```

Comment: This is what I want but I have many if conditions , above solution is best if there was only 1 condition.

Comment: @Ajit what do you mean? If there is more than one condition then call the function several times. Please edit your quesiton accordingly in case your example is not showing what you actually want to do

Comment: Slightly changed my code with a one line comment just below the code.

Comment: @Ajit so you call `operation` twice with `AND` as parameter and twice with `OR`. Sorry I dont see the problem

Comment: ah, I get it now. Thanks !!

Comment: I've used the latter example a few times when adding stuff to variants.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pointers to funtions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


bool oper1(bool a, bool b) {
    return a || b;
}


bool oper2(bool a, bool b) {
    return a && b;
}

int main() {
    bool a = true, b = false;
    auto oper = oper1;
    if (oper(a, b)) {
        std::cout << "OR\n";
    }
    oper = oper2;
    if (oper(a, b)) {
        std::cout << "AND\n";
    }
}
```

First you define all your conditions and later you can switch the condition by setting the variable.

You can also use inheritance and functors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

class Operator {
public:
    virtual bool eval(bool a, bool b) = 0;
};

class OrOperator : public Operator {
public:
    bool eval(bool a, bool b) {
        return a || b;
    }
};

class AndOperator : public Operator {
public:
    bool eval(bool a, bool b) {
        return a && b;
    }
};

class VariableOperator : public Operator {
public:
    VariableOperator(bool val) : val(val) {}
    bool eval(bool a, bool b) {
        return val;
    }
private:
    bool val;
};

int main() {
    bool a = true, b = false;
    std::unique_ptr<Operator> oper(new OrOperator);
    if (oper->eval(a, b)) {
        std::cout << "OR\n";
    }
    oper.reset(new AndOperator);
    if (oper->eval(a, b)) {
        std::cout << "AND\n";
    }
    oper.reset(new VariableOperator(true));
    if (oper->eval(a, b)) {
        std::cout << "VARIABLE\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach also looks good. I am evaluating if I can use this. Will update here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
void somFunc()
{
  std::vector< std::function< bool(bool, bool) > > operators = {
    [](bool a, bool b){ return a && b; },
    [](bool a, bool b){ return a || b; }
  };
  for ( auto& op : operators )
  {
      if ( op( a, b ) )
      {
      }
      else if ( op( a1, b1 ) )
      {
      }
  }
}
```

You can add more operators or change the parameter types easily enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with **CRTP** too:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

template<class T>
class Operation
{
public:
   bool eval(bool a, bool b)
   {
      return this->impl().eval(a,b);
   }
private:
   T& impl() { return static_cast<T&>(*this); }
};

class AndOperation : public Operation<AndOperation>
{
public:
   bool eval(bool a, bool b)
   {
      return a && b;
   }
};

class OrOperation : public Operation<OrOperation>
{
public:
   bool eval(bool a, bool b)
   {
      return a || b;
   }
};

int main()
{
  AndOperation andOp;
  auto anonOp = std::make_unique<OrOperation>();
  std::cout << andOp.eval(true, true) << std::endl;
  std::cout << anonOp->eval(false,false);
}
```

see **[live example here](http://cpp.sh/4rlc7)**

What are the advantages of **CRTP** over **virtual inheritance**? 
CRTP is a case of *static polymorphism*. Here's some references:

[Compile time vs run time polymorphism in C++ advantages/disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875989/compile-time-vs-run-time-polymorphism-in-c-advantages-disadvantages)

[What is the motivation behind static polymorphism in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062733/what-is-the-motivation-behind-static-polymorphism-in-c)

[C++: How is this technique of compile-time polymorphism called and what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43831896/c-how-is-this-technique-of-compile-time-polymorphism-called-and-what-are-the)

[The cost of dynamic (virtual calls) vs. static (CRTP) dispatch in C++](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/12/05/the-cost-of-dynamic-virtual-calls-vs-static-crtp-dispatch-in-c)

Comment: What are the advantages of CRTP over simple inheritance?

Comment: Is it possible to make `OrOperation::evalImpl` protected?

Comment: @ThomasSablik you made a point. I'm going to edit the answer with a more correct implementation which fix your point too

Comment: That was no critics. I like your answer and I'm interested.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I'm aware of that, but you make me notice I made a little mistake and I'm going to correct it. It's a way to improve yourself too

Comment: @ThomasSablik It avoids the need for virtual dispatch. This is called _static polymorphism_.

Comment: **CRTP** is useful when the set of derived classes is finite. As @LightnessRacesinOrbit mentioned, you can achieve *polyphormism* without virtual dispatching.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make `somFunc()` a template, and accept any function that accepts two arguments and returns a value that can be tested with `if`.

```
 #include <functional>    // for binary operations in std

 template<class Operation> void somfunc(Operation oper)
 {
      if (oper(a,b))
      {
            // whatever
      }
 }

 int main()
 {
      somFunc(std::logical_and<int>());
      somFunc(std::logical_or<int>());
      somFunc(std::plus<int>());         //  addition

       //   pass a lambda

      somFunc([](int a, int b) -> int {return a + b;});   // lambda form of addition
 }
```

In the above, I've assumed the variables `a` and `b` (which have been used in the question, but types unspecified) are of type `int`.